# Why is result displaying result plus previous result in loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an image and name displaying in a new div. However, I have run into a problem where the next time a person enters name and picture and presses save, their userDiv shows their name plus the previous users name. For example, there are two users: User 1 and User 2. When I select all users and loop through the results the names are logging differently. User one shows up as "User 1", but User 2 shows up as "User 1 User 2". From a quick look around I think it is because innerHTML gets all content from the parent div, but I'm not sure.

```
    var htmlStr="";
  var theID;
  var theName;
  var thePhoto;
  var len = results.rows.length;
  console.log(len);
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        theID = results.rows.item(i).id;
        console.log(theID);
        theName = results.rows.item(i).username;
            htmlStr += theName;
        console.log(theName);
        thePhoto = results.rows.item(i).imagepath;
        console.log(thePhoto);

        var imageHold= new Image();
        imageHold.src = thePhoto;
        console.log("this is the src:"+imageHold.src);
        var userDiv = document.createElement("div");//Create the div
        userDiv.innerHTML=htmlStr;
        userDiv.appendChild(imageHold);
        document.getElementById('showUsers').appendChild(userDiv);//append it to the document
        userDiv.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Unbelieveable. I had tried that but mustn't have refreshed or something. Will accept when allowed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `var htmlStr="";` and declare it within the loop on each iteration. So change

```
htmlStr += theName;
```

to

```
var htmlStr = theName;
```

and this should resolve your issue

Comment: You can keep the `var htmlStr="";` where it is and just change the second line to `htmlStr = theName;`. Moving the `var` doesn't change the scope. The real problem is the `+=`.

Comment: @gpojd you are right, i think it just reads easier if you put the declaration within the loop - it shows the variable is created for the purpose of the loop ... i guess its personal preference